# Why does my search not checking all tag elements? Bootstrap, JS

Tags: javascript, search, filter, bootstrap-4

Almost absolutely noob, working on my second project with bootstrap and JS.
So I made search form and several cards with two paragraphs in each.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center my-5">
        <input class="form-control col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-8" id="myInput" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Поиск">
        <button class="btn btn-outline ml-2 my-xs-2 col-xs-8 " style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 700;">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="row" id="myList" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li class="card mb-4 box-shadow"><p>Adele</p><p>2001</p></li>
        <li class="card mb-4 box-shadow"><p>Agnes</p><p>1980</p></li>

        <li class="card mb-4 box-shadow"><p>Billy</p><p>2010</p></li>
        <li class="card mb-4 box-shadow"><p>Bob</p><p>1530</p></li>

        <li class="card mb-4 box-shadow"><p>Calvin</p></li>
        <li class="card mb-4 box-shadow"><p>Christina</p></li>
        <li class="card mb-4 box-shadow"><p>Cindy</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My script:

```
function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, p, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById('myInput');
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myList");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        p = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        txtValue = p.textContent || p.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

When I enter the name it works but when I enter the year - no. Why does it ignore second paragraph and how should I change the script to solve the problem?

Comment: The reason your code is *ignoring* your second paragraph tag with the year is because you’re looking at just the first P tag. In the `getElementsByTagName` line, you just get the first tag because you have `[0]` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rich DeBourke mentioned, the problem lies in using the 0 index on this line:

```
p = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
```

I suggest you use the following method:

```
function myFunction() {
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  const inputValue = input.value.toUpperCase();

  const ul = document.getElementById("myList");
  const lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (let li of lis) {
    const [pName, pYear] = li.getElementsByTagName("p");

    // We assume on this example that the name's paragraph 
    // will always exist, but the year may not
    const textPName = pName.innerText.toUpperCase();
    const textPYear = pYear?.innerText.toUpperCase();

    if (
      textPName.startsWith(inputValue) ||
      (textPYear && textPYear.startsWith(inputValue))
    ) {
      li.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      li.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Some of the advantages of this new method are:

- Variables are defined closer to where they are being used, and are given names which are more tightly coupled with their identity within the method.
- We use const instead of var where appropriate.
- We use for/of instead of a basic for loop because we don't need the index.
- We destructure the elements of the array of li into reasonably named variables that we can use immediately.
- We consider edge cases on our if statement (the year may not be present).
- We use innerText (the simpler alternative) when obtaining the content of the elements and we set the display to block (instead of an empty string) on our if statement, because that is the default display.

Hope this helps!